# Какие существуют инструменты для разработки GUI десктопных приложений?

Tags: c#, c++, gui

Как и с помощью каких инструментов разрабатываются gui десктопных приложений? Сам являюсь web-разработчиком, и в вебе gui привязывается к front-end, и пишется на html, css, js. А что используется при разработке gui десктопных приложений? И как построен сам процесс?

Comment: Все операционки предоставляют некий API, посредством которого возможно создание гуя. Далее, можно пользоваться голым апи или использовать более высокоуровневые, а то и кросс-платформенные обёртки. [List of platform-independent GUI libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_platform-independent_GUI_libraries)

Comment: C# и C++ это совсем разные языки и разные подходы к разработке десктопа. На них нельзя дать общий ответ :) Оставьте один тэг

Comment: Возможно, вам как веб-разработчику, стоит посмотреть на [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework))

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу только за С++
Есть много вариантов -

QT - https://www.qt.io/ Библиотека для создания кросс-платформенных гуев (поддерживает свой генератор make файла qmake и CMake)

Masking - олдовый вариант (под dos и т.д)

FLTK - https://www.fltk.org/ - по суди обертка над OGL

OpenGL (GLUT) - https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/windowtoolkits/ тру вариант для создания красивой графики

GTK - https://www.gtk.org/ - конкурент QT работает под X и Wayland

Процесс построен как все процессы разработки на C++ : используем библиотеку которая обеспечивает связь с X или fb и реализуем бизнес-логику приложения

Comment: https://github.com/vurtun/nuklear ещё доволно неплоха.

Comment: Еще есть [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/).

Comment: nuklear сишная же

Comment: что не мешает быть ей неплохой, заметь :)

Comment: это не значит что она плохая) это значит что спрашивали про с++

Comment: хотя все равно и x и wayland  все си блин)))

Answer (score 1):

Из тех что знаю и в которых работал это Qt и WinForms.

Qt Creator предоставляет средства визуального программирования пользовательского интерефейса (чистый с++). Есть редактор формы, позволяющий располагать на форме элементы (кнопки, лейблы, текстбоксы) и программировать события связанные с ними. 
[image: ВЫглядит как то так:]

Еще в Qt есть такая фича как QtQuick и собственный язык разметки - QML (думаю это будет для вас ближе). Я в ту степь не лез, подробнее рассказать не могу. Но точно знаю что с помощью того что написал выше тоже можно наклепать GUI.

[Тут вроде неплохо написано](https://webhamster.ru/mytetrashare/index/mtb0/1526295073wqlj6r8r8h)

WinForms это API для разработки пользовательских интерфейсов и является частью .NET. В отличии от Qt не настолько кросс-платформенный и больше подходит для разработки под винду.
Средства визуального программирования под WinForms предоставляет Microsoft Visual Studio. Можно писать как на с# так и на CLR/С++(так уже никто не делает). 
На шарпах достаточно удобно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На шарпах winform давно устарел и  сейчас стоит использовать wpf.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко старый != устаревший. WinForms всего лишь обертка над WinAPI. Да ее не довели до ума и бросили в угоду "быстрой разработке на WPF", который, кстати, тоже уже забросили и не развивают, так что по "модным" критериям оценки он тоже устарел. У любого инструмента, будь то кувалда или GUI-фреймворк, есть свое назначение и область применения, если их не соблюдать - будет боль, много боли.